# How to produce a classification table of predicted vs actual values

Tags: r, neural-network, prediction

I'm new to R and neutral network and haven't been able to figure out how predict variable from trained network (neural network) and produce classification table of predicted vs actual values. I just haven't been able to understand the code meaning of classification table vs actual . I would greatly appreciate it if you explain the code. This is what I have done so far:

```
model_Wine <- train(wine~., wine_df, method='nnet', trace=FALSE)
prediction <- predict(model_Wine, wine_df)
table(prediction, wine_df$wine)

prediction  A  B  C
         A 59  0  0
         B  0 71  0
         C  0  0 48
```

how do i produce classification table of predicted vs actual "wine" values?
Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661025/classification-table-for-logistic-regression-in-r

Comment: What packages are you using? I don't totally get how this table differs from what you want

Comment: I use : > wine_df <-  read_delim(url, delim = ",")   data. that's what im trying to understand a meaning of classification table of predicted vs actual "wine" values. As i can make a prediction table, that's easy part, but i cant understand classification table of actual values.

Comment: @NelsonGon, thank you for the link! its something i was looking for!